# UnityEngine.Cursor does not contain a definition for 'lockState'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am assuming I am missing some sort of import, however I cannot seem to see what it is I am supposed to be importing, my code seems ok to me..

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class RayShooter : MonoBehaviour {
       private Camera _camera;
       // Use this for initialization
       void Start () {
         _camera = GetComponent<Camera> ();
         Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

       }
   }
```

The same issue applies for CursorLockMode

Thanks!

Comment: Are you importing any other namespaces in other code that might contain another Cursor/CursorLockMode? Where is this script attached? Have you tried saving/restarting/building a clean solution?

Comment: @TobiahZarlez I don't believe I am no! The script is simply attached to a Capsule I haven't tried saving and rebuilding yet! But will give that a go cheers! The other thing I've found is that I am using Unity 4 so I am wondering if I am supposed to upgrade to 5 as the book I am learning from is using 5!

Comment: Aha! That very likely might be it. Which version of Unity 4 are you using? There was an older way to do this that was deprecated last year. I forgot exactly which version, but that may be your problem.

Unless there is a reason to stick with 4, the latest version of 5 is great for learning Unity development. I'd recommend upgrading

Comment: Do not use Unity 4.  You must change to Unity5.  Books are useless.  if it's that old it's useless.

Comment: @TobiahZarlez Thanks! I've began to download it now! :) I was using 4.6 previously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was because I was using Unity 4! After upgrading to Unity 5 the functions were available!